# C# can not deserialize a Json object

Tags: c#, json

I hava a Json file looks like this :

```
{"APPMYPETS":{"note":"backend app mobile","esito":"Non applicabile"},

{"CANINA":{"note":"backend app mobile","esito":"Non applicabile"}}
```

my try in creating map class looks like this :

```
class RootObj
{
    public CodElettra elettra{get;set;}
}
public class CodElettra 
{
    public string note {get:set;}
    public string esito {get;set;}
}
```

I've used Newtonsoft.Json;

```
string json = r.ReadToEnd();

var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObj>(json);

var x is null
```

I've tried online to convert Json object to C# class but it does not works .
Thanks for you help

Comment: The thing is that `APPMYPETS` and `CANINA` are different from `elettra`.

Comment: "it does not works" is *never* enough information. What happens? Please post a [mcve] so we can replicate the problem. It doesn't help that the names in your JSON don't appear to match the names in your classes, other than `note`...

Comment: Json object contains 1K object "APPMYPETS" and "CANINA" are dynamic other fields "note" and "esito" are static

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/3luoXo

Comment: please take a look at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the property names are dynamic, try deserializing into a `Dictionary<string, CodElettra>` instead of `RootObject`.

```
var x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, CodElettra>>(json);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/cZJ2Q0

Comment: it works of course I was blind not to recognize this immediately thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

According to JSON string `{"CANINA":{"note":"backend app mobile","esito":"Non applicabile"}}`

your c# class should be like this:

```
public class CANINA
{
    public string note { get; set; }
    public string esito { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public CANINA CANINA { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:** I realised that your complete JSON string is not valid, i'm assuming your complete json string is

```
{
    "APPMYPETS": {
        "note": "backend app mobile",
        "esito": "Non applicabile"
    },
    "CANINA": {
        "note": "backend app mobile",
        "esito": "Non applicabile"
    }
}
```

Then your c# class should look like this:

```
public class APPMYPETS
{
    public string note { get; set; }
    public string esito { get; set; }
}

public class CANINA
{
    public string note { get; set; }
    public string esito { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public APPMYPETS APPMYPETS { get; set; }
    public CANINA CANINA { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok so I write 1k classes ? "CANINA" and "APPMYPETS" are dinamyc are values I need to map them in some other ways .Unfortunately has been serialized reading from a csv file

Comment: if the keys are dynamic then use JToken in C#. Google it.